# Concentration of NaIO3 using hypo

Tags: physical-chemistry, titration

> $$\ce{2NaIO3 + 5NaHSO3 -> 3NaHSO4 + H2O + I2 + Na2SO4}$$
>   $\mathrm{20ml}$ of $\ce{NaIO3}$ solution reacted with excess $\ce{NaHSO3}$ releasing $\ce{I2}$ that can oxidize $\mathrm{20ml}$ of $\mathrm{0.1M}$ hypo. What is the molarity of $\ce{NaIO3}$

The reaction of iodine with hypo is 
$$\ce{I2 + 2Na2S2O3 -> 2NaI + Na2S4O6}$$
moles of hypo used is $\mathrm{20\times 10^{-3}\times 0.1=20\times 10^{-4}}$

Therefore moles of $\ce{I2}$ reacted is $\mathrm{10\times 10^{-4}}$

Hence, moles of $\ce{NaIO3}$ reacted is $\mathrm{20\times 10^{-4}}$

Therefore concentration of $\ce{NaIO3}$ is $\mathrm{\frac{20\times 10^{-4}}{20\times 10^{-3}}}=\mathrm{0.1M}$

But answer given is $\mathrm{0.02M}$